.NET Aspire - Bad loading of connection strings
I made a "manual" addition of Azure function to .NET Aspire solution. Everything seems ok. I do have to manually run debug, but that's fine.
Extension:
public static IResourceBuilder<ExecutableResource> AddAzureFunction<TServiceMetadata>(
    this IDistributedApplicationBuilder builder,
    string name,
    int port,
    int debugPort)
    where TServiceMetadata : IProjectMetadata, new()
{
    var serviceMetadata = new TServiceMetadata();
    var projectPath = serviceMetadata.ProjectPath;
    var projectDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(projectPath)!;

    var args = new[]
    {
    "host",
    "start",
    "--port",
    port.ToString(),
    "--nodeDebugPort",
    debugPort.ToString(),
    "--pause-on-error",
    "–-dotnet-isolated-debug",
    "--launch-profile Aspire",
    "--debug",
    "--inspect=5858"
};

    return builder.AddExecutable(name, "func", projectDirectory, args)
        .WithEnvironment("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Aspire")
        .WithEnvironment("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT", "Aspire")
        .WithEnvironment("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", "Aspire")
        .WithOtlpExporter();
}

Aspire settings:
var blobs = storage.AddBlobs("AppBlobStorage");
var tables = storage.AddTables("AppTableStorage");
var bus = builder.AddConnectionString("AppMessaging");

builder.AddAzureFunction<Projects.FunctionApp>("FunctionApp", 7121, 7122)
        .WithReference(blobs)
        .WithReference(tables)
        .WithReference(bus)
        .WithEnvironment("ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace", bus)
        .WithEnvironment(
            "AzureWebJobsStorage",
            () =>
            {
                return blobs.Resource.ConnectionStringExpression.ValueExpression ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string is null");
            }
            );

There is one problem though. The specified connection strings only ever appear in azure functions. I.e. once none is filled in correctly. sometimes one and sometimes all.
AppTableStorage not load:

Second time empty Blob storage:

Do you know what this could be?
Thanks

Can you add a breakpoint or a log statement bevor going into the AddAzureFunctions Method and check if the environment variables are set?

Yes variables are set.
